# How would I prevent an event until the code is done via import/export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, import, export

=================== Progress Update ===================

I've made my first Async function according to [Mozilla](https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/) and [another](https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/) tutorial. However, it couldn't prevent the event as I expected. It goes stacking when I click multiple times before the whole code is done.

[image]

My expectation is using async and promise to disable the event until the entire code is done which is the way that I use callback like [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/pMzpgr).

Additionally, I can't fully understand the concept of Async and Promise. I think the `Async + Promise function` separates the code as itself such as the bookmark of the book in real life? It's really hard to understand what's going on inside of the code.

Can somebody explain to me that how async and promise work in the code and prevent the event?

This is a result that I've done so far:

```
class Async {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelectorAll(elem)
        this.flag = true;
        this.selector(this.elem, 'click');
    }
    selector(node, eventName) {
        node.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => this.group(e))
        })
    }
    waiting() {
        if (this.flag) {
            this.flag = false;
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(console.log('waiting . . .'))
                }, 2000)
            })
        }
    }
    result() {
        console.log('test');
        this.flag = true;
    }
    async group(e) {
        const a = await this.waiting();
        const b = await this.result();
    }
}
const async = new Async('.button');
```

=================== Original Question ===================

I'm separating the code blocks with import/export in Node js for looking clearer when I refactoring it.

A problem is boolean flag called `this.flag` doesn't prevent the event overriding when I pass it to `init.js` as a parameter like this:

[image]

See the code first:

```
// =================== init ===================
'use strict';
import Terminal from './terminal.js';
import Touch from './touch.js';
export const slider = (function() {
    class Slider {
        constructor(elem) {
            this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
            this.flag = false;
            this.terminal = new Terminal(this.elem);
            this.touch = new Touch(this.elem);
            this.terminal.insert(this.elem, 'click', this.touch.clicked.bind(this.touch));
        }
        wait(flag, callback) {
            flag = false; // the boolean can't prevent the event overriding right now.
            let bound = callback.bind(this);
            console.log('waiting . . .');
            setTimeout(bound, 1000, flag);
        }
        done(flag) {
            console.log('done');
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return {
        init: new Slider('.contents')
    }
}())

// =================== terminal.js ===================
export default class Terminal {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
    }
    insert(node, eventName, callback) {
        node.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
    }
}

// =================== touch.js ===================
import {slider} from './a.js';
export default class Touch {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.flag = true;
    }
    clicked(e) {
        if (this.flag) {
            console.log(`clicked`);
            let slide = slider;
            slide.init.wait(this.flag, slide.init.done);
        }
    }
}
```

But the weird thing is, when I replace the both functions `wait()` and `result()` to `touch.js`, it prevents the event until the countdown is done.

```
// touch.js
wait(callback) {
    this.flag = false;
    let bound = callback.bind(this);
    console.log('waiting . . .');
    setTimeout(bound, 1000);
}
done(flag) {
    console.log('done');
    this.flag = true;
}
```

I would like to know why the flag can't prevent the event when it passed to the another `js file` and how to make it disables the event temporarily.

Comment: Why do you need a class to be wrapped in an IIFE in a modular system?

Comment: @El. For double secure? Actually idk. I'm new at JS and I wanted to make my own structure style.

Comment: When you create a module in JS at low level at compile time it will be wrapped in `IIFE` and using `IIFE` is needless inside modules. If you want to hold an event for other processes to end you have to use `Async/Await` or `pormise`.

Comment: No, There's no need to IIFE. Just use asynchronous programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

Generally speaking

- The `async/await` pattern got introduced with ES2017 of JavaScript and is syntactic sugar for the older Promise's
- Some older browsers don't support `async/await`
- `async` is a newer way of saying `return Promise((resolve) => { ... })`.
- `await` is the counterpart to `async` and is the newer way of saying `.then(result => { ... })`.

  - `await` can only be used in functions marked as `async`
- `try/catch` is the counterpart to `.catch(error => { ... })`. It is not actually new, but you can use it in this context.

You can read more about `async/await` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

#### Code

I have made some minor changes to your code, so that it makes more sense and written some comments, so that you understand everything that is happening here.

```
class Async {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelectorAll(elem)
        this.isRunning = false; // <-- Rename the flag variable to something more meaningful
        this.selector(this.elem, 'click');
    }
    selector(node, eventName) {
        node.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => this.group(e))
        })
    }
    waiting() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <-- Move the Promise to here so that every codepath returns something
            if (!this.isRunning) {
                this.isRunning = true;
                console.log('Waiting ... '); // <-- Move the waiting before the timeout, because inside it is not actually waiting, its rather done

                setTimeout(() => { // <-- setTimeout runs the provided function after the provided time in milliseconds elapsed
                    this.isRunning = false; // <-- Switch the isRunning after the timeout, because that makes more sense (because now it is not running anymore)
                    resolve('Done'); // <-- Change the text to done and actually resolve it (eg. remove the console.log)
                }, 2000)
            } else {
                reject('There is already a button function running'); // <-- reject is like throwing an error
            }
        })
    }
    result() {
        console.log('test');
    }
    async group(e) {
        try {
            const a = await this.waiting(); // <-- Assigns 'Done' to the variable a
            console.log(a); // <-- prints the message

            this.result(); // <-- prints 'test' immidiatly after the above console.log
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error); // <-- Prints the reject message in case the button is already running
        }

        /* group could also be written with the old syntax like this:

        this.waiting().then(result => {
            console.log(result); // Will print "Done" after 2000 milliseconds

            this.result(); // Will print test instantly after the above console.log(). You dont need to await it, because it is not an async function
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // Will print the reject message in case the button is already running
        });

        */
    }
}
const asyncButton = new Async('.button'); // <-- Don't use async as a variable name. It's a reserved keyword
```

#### Running Example

It is the same code again, but without comments, so that you can test it directly here on StackOverflow.

```js
class Async {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelectorAll(elem)
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.selector(this.elem, 'click');
    }
    selector(node, eventName) {
        node.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => this.group(e))
        })
    }
    waiting() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            if (!this.isRunning) {
                this.isRunning = true;
                console.log('Waiting ... '); 
                
                setTimeout(() => { 
                    this.isRunning = false;
                    resolve('Done');
                }, 2000)
            } else {
                reject('There is already a button function running'); 
            }
        })
    }
    result() {
        console.log('test');
    }
    async group(e) {
        try {
          const a = await this.waiting(); 
          console.log(a); 
          this.result();
        } catch(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
const asyncButton = new Async('.button');
```

```html
<button class="button">Test</button>
```

Comment: So the `promise` and `async/await` is like `prototype` and `class` syntax, am I understanding right away? A syntactic sugar of promise?

Comment: Yes. It is syntactic sugar. But keep in mind, that some older browsers only support Promises. And some **even older** browsers (and Internet Explorer) don't even support Promises. Have updated my answer with this explanation @sniffingdoggo

Comment: Ohhhhhh okay, now I finally understood 100%. Thank you for detailed answer :-)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask! @sniffingdoggo

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution. Adding await functions into the boolean flag is working.

```
class Async {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelectorAll(elem)
        this.flag = true;
        this.selector(this.elem, 'click');
    }
    selector(node, eventName) {
        node.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => this.group(e))
        })
    }
    waiting() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(console.log('waiting . . .'))
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
    result() {
        console.log('test');
        this.flag = true;
    }
    async group(e) {
        // console.log(this.flag);
        if (this.flag) {
            this.flag = false;
            console.log('test');
            const a = await this.waiting();
            const b = await this.result();
        }

    }
}
const async = new Async('.button');
```

Comment: A better way is usually to disable the button, once it is clicked and show some spinner to provide visual feedback to the user